# goroutine to print odd and even number alternatively is running into deadlock

Tags: go

I am currently learning golang. I wanted to check how golang channels work. I have created a program where two goroutines will print odd and even numbers alternatively. Even though the program is printing correctly, it is showing a deadlock error at the end. It is not clear from error message what is causing this issue.

```
func main() {
    even := make(chan bool)
    odd := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        defer close(odd)
        for i := 0; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            <-even
            print("Even ====>")
            println(i)
            odd <- true
        }
    }()
    var wait sync.WaitGroup
    wait.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            _, ok := <-odd
            if !ok {
                wait.Done()
                return
            }
            print("Odd ====>")
            println(i)
            even <- true
        }
    }()
    even <- true
    wait.Wait()
}
```

[Edit]
Thanks everyone for your reply. I wrote the following code to solve the problem.

```
func main() {
    even := make(chan bool)
    odd := make(chan bool)
    done := make(chan bool)
    //var wait sync.WaitGroup
    //wait.Add(2)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            <-even
            print("Even ====>")
            println(i)
            odd <- true
        }
        close(odd)
        close(even)
        done <- true
        // wait.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        for i := 1; ; i += 2 {
            _, ok := <-odd
            if !ok {
                //wait.Done()
                return
            }
            print("Odd ====>")
            println(i)
            select {
            case even <- true:
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    even <- true
    //wait.Wait()
    <-done
}
```

Comment: Hi...nice to have you on Stackoverflow but can you maybe copy the code in your go.dev link and share it directly in your question because, in the future, when that go.dev link expires, your current question will no longer be relevant for future readers.

Comment: why is this so difficult to do this using Go primitives. I thought this should be an easy task . The diificulty arises when the order is needed to be maintained. Are there any other approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: @Technical Shil this is printing the number sequentially but there is a deadlock at the end of the program. Did you happen to test it before posing it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by

1. Removing the for upper bound for the second gofunc (line 20)
2. `select`ing when writing to `even` (line 28)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you don't end up linking your code, here it is for future readers

```golang
package main

import "sync"

func main() {
    even := make(chan bool)
    odd := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        defer close(odd)
        for i := 0; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            <-even
            print("Even ====>")
            println(i)
            odd <- true
        }
    }()
    var wait sync.WaitGroup
    wait.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i += 2 {
            _, ok := <-odd
            if !ok {
                wait.Done()
                return
            }
            print("Odd ====>")
            println(i)
            even <- true
        }
    }()
    even <- true
    wait.Wait()
}
```

The deadlock is likely quite easy to figure that it occurs here `odd <- true` as a result of a write into an unbuffered (or filled up) channel.
On the last iteration of your second goroutine having this loop `for i := 1; i <= 10; i += 2 {`, the channel `odd` has been written into already by the first goroutine but the second goroutine can't read it because the iteration condition no longer matches because `i + 2 = 11` at that particular iteration and `11 > 10` which causes the iteration to stop and the channel to stay filled.

Now, the other goroutine trying to write into the `odd` channel gets blocked as a result and stays blocked forever but since the runtime can easily detect this...it yields a deadlock pretty quickly afterward.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified way, without using select

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"

var even = make(chan bool)
var odd = make(chan bool)
var done = make(chan bool)

func main() {
    go oddPrint()
    go evenPrint()
    even <- true
    <-done
}

func evenPrint() {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i += 2 {
        <-even
        fmt.Println(i)
        if i == 10 {
            close(even)
            close(odd)
            done <- true
            break
        }
        odd <- true
    }

}

func oddPrint() {
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i += 2 {
        <-odd
        fmt.Println(i)
        even <- true
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/BGb-er060Tk

Answer (score 0):

Using WaitGroup and Two Goroutines.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go PrintEven(&wg)
    go PrintOdd(&wg)
    wg.Wait()
}

func PrintOdd(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 1; i < 100; i += 2 {
        fmt.Println("odd", i)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func PrintEven(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 2; i <= 100; i += 2 {
        fmt.Println("even", i)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LVOuIztL3mJ)